# Verifying user details and auto-login Windows

Tags: windows, vb.net, authentication, passwords

1. How do you dig out a logged in user's User Name?
2. How do you verify if a password given matches with the one really used to log into the Windows machine?
3. How do we auto-login by providing these verified details you say at a specific time by regularly checking the time using a timer?

Is this possible in VB.NET?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will authenticate a username and password against the active directory. You will need to import the System.DirectoryServices namespace. You'll also need to specify the LDAP path for the domain in the "domain" var, such as "dc=mydomain,dc=com".

Also, have a look at the My.User.* stuff.

```
Private Function Authenticate(userName As String, password As String, domain As String) As           Boolean
    Dim authentic As Boolean = False
    Try
        Dim entry As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & domain, userName, password)
        Dim nativeObject As Object = entry.NativeObject
        authentic = True
    Catch generatedExceptionName As DirectoryServicesCOMException
    End Try
    Return authentic
End Function
```

Comment: I used domain = "GC://dc=mydomain,dc=com" and dropped the LDAP:// from the call to DirectoryEntry constructor after reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973834.aspx.

Comment: I know this is old answer however this helped

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's probably done using Windows Authentication or similar. Verification usually done against Active Directory.

You can automatically log people in using it as well, so long as they're signed into Windows and (I believe) you're running an IIS server, or similar.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add references:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.DirectoryServices.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll
```

You have to import:

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
```

Function to validate:

```
Private Function ValidateUsername(ByVal Domain As String, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean
    Dim context As PrincipalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain)
    Try
        If context.ValidateCredentials(Username, Password) = True Then
            Return True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Function to set autologon:

```
    Public Shared Sub EnableDomainAutologon(ByVal Domain As String, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String)
    Try
        Dim reg As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", True)
        reg.SetValue("AutoAdminLogon", "1", RegistryValueKind.String)
        reg.SetValue("DefaultUserName", Username, RegistryValueKind.String)
        reg.SetValue("DefaultPassword", Password, RegistryValueKind.String)
        reg.SetValue("DefaultDomainName", Domain, RegistryValueKind.String)
        reg.Close()
        MsgBox("The autologon feature has been enabled!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Autologon Enabled")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

For setting up the registry you need the administrator rights so you have to set the level to "requireAdministrator" in app.manifest:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

The function to validate the username and password it may take a while.